# How to switch rows to columns and vice versa in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have problem to switch rows to columns and vice versa in SQL Server 2008, I have tried any queries to a solution but I did not get a proper results.

I've a table as following:

```
declare @tmpTable table 
(name varchar(20), date_ date, sales_code char(1), sales smallint, earned int)

insert into @tmpTable 
values ('Robert', '2016/8/1', 'A', 2, 30),
('Robert', '2016/8/1', 'B', 3, 45),
('Robert', '2016/8/2', 'B', 1, 15),
('Robert', '2016/8/3', 'B', 2, 30),
('Jhon', '2016/8/1', 'A', 3, 45),
('Jhon', '2016/8/2', 'A', 3, 45),
('Jhon', '2016/8/3', 'B', 2, 30)

select * from @tmpTable;
```

Result:

```
Name        date_           sales_code  sales   earned
------      ----------      ----------  -----   ------
Robert      2016-08-01      A           2       30
Robert      2016-08-01      B           3       45
Robert      2016-08-02      B           1       15
Robert      2016-08-03      B           2       30
Jhon        2016-08-01      A           3       45
Jhon        2016-08-02      A           3       45
Jhon        2016-08-03      B           2       30
```

Then, I have next query :

```
select * from (
select name, 'sales_code' as category, date_, sales_code from (
select * from (
SELECT  name, date_
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sales_code [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') sales_code
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(max), sales) [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') sales
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(max), earned) [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') earned
FROM @tmpTable t
GROUP BY name, date_
) as a
) as a
) as a
pivot (
    max(sales_code) FOR date_ IN ([2016/8/1], [2016/8/2], [2016/8/3])
)as pv

union all

select * from (
select name, 'sales' as category, date_, sales from (
select * from (
SELECT  name, date_
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sales_code [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') sales_code
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(max), sales) [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') sales
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(max), earned) [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') earned
FROM @tmpTable t
GROUP BY name, date_
) as a
) as a
) as a
pivot (
    max(sales) FOR date_ IN ([2016/8/1], [2016/8/2], [2016/8/3])
)as pv

union all

select * from (
select name, 'earned' as category, date_, earned from (
select * from (
SELECT  name, date_
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sales_code [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') sales_code
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(max), sales) [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') sales
                ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(max), earned) [text()]
         FROM @tmpTable 
         WHERE date_ = t.date_
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') earned
FROM @tmpTable t
GROUP BY name, date_
) as a
) as a
) as a
pivot (
    max(earned) FOR date_ IN ([2016/8/1], [2016/8/2], [2016/8/3])
)as pv
```

It will display the result:

```
name        category    2016/8/1        2016/8/2    2016/8/3
-------     --------    --------        -------     --------
Jhon        sales_code  A, B, A         B, A        B, B
Robert      sales_code  A, B, A         B, A        B, B
Jhon        sales       2, 3, 3         1, 3        2, 2
Robert      sales       2, 3, 3         1, 3        2, 2
Jhon        earned      30, 45, 45      15, 45      30, 30
Robert      earned      30, 45, 45      15, 45      30, 30
```

But, I would like to get the following result:

```
name        category    2016/8/1    2016/8/2    2016/8/3
----        --------    --------    --------    --------
Robert      sales_code  A, B        B           B
Robert      sales       2, 3        1           2
Robert      earned      30, 45      15          30
Jhon        sales_code  A           A           B
Jhon        sales       3           3           2
Jhon        earned      45          45          30
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, I have updated my question, sorry I am new in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to unpivot your data.. to do this, all data types much match, so you need to convert the 2 numeric columns to varchars.

still use stuff before you unpivot to get the combined values per name, date_  but use distinct to only get the name, date_ values once.

after you unpivot, you just need to pivot again.

```
SELECT  *
FROM (  SELECT  DISTINCT
                Name, 
                date_,
                sales_code = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + sales_code 
                                    FROM @tmpTable t2 
                                    WHERE t2.Name = t.Name AND t2.date_ = t.date_ 
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
                sales      = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, sales) 
                                    FROM @tmpTable t2 
                                    WHERE t2.Name = t.Name AND t2.date_ = t.date_ 
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
                earned     = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, earned) 
                                    FROM @tmpTable t2 
                                    WHERE t2.Name = t.Name AND t2.date_ = t.date_ 
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
        FROM    @tmpTable t) t
UNPIVOT (
    val 
    FOR category IN (sales_code, sales, earned)
) up
PIVOT (
    MAX(val)
    FOR date_ IN ([2016-08-01], [2016-08-02], [2016-08-03])
) p
ORDER BY name DESC, 
        category DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much you save my day.